# How to build two or three different modules or project in to one single project in Angular 5+

Tags: angular

How can I design a framework which will help me to divide module into two category one is core module and another is add-on module. Now suppose the core module is used or common in 4 to 5 countries but they have thr own module as well so finally what I want is when there are any country specific changes is done then how can I build their module with our core module to run it as a single project.

Do I need to use any custom module or do I need to make any changes which will build these two module into one single project.

Comment: I am using [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) to build multiple sub-project or plugins in a big project. This is not a problem with Angular. I think this is about front-end architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using angular-cli. You can create [library](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library) and store common components and services there.

```
ng generate library my-lib
```

Then you can create multiple [applications](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-application) and reuse there.

```
ng generate application [name]
```

after that you can install your lib

```
npm install my-lib
```

Comment: The common components or core module is too big in size so is it ok to go with this lib approach ?

Comment: @AbhinayHonrao yes, but try to split by modules

Comment: Is there any other way by which I can achieve this ?